# Equivalent of "To whom it may concern:"

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, saludos, formalidad

When writing formal letters in English where there is no named recipient (for example, a job application sent to a Human Resources department, or a letter sent to an organization in general as opposed to an individual), the letter often starts:

> To whom it may concern:

When composing formal letters or emails in Spanish, what is the equivalent phrase used when the particular individual who will be receiving the letter is unknown?

Comment: In mi opinión it would be 'A quien pueda concernir'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The literal translation is:

> A quien corresponda

But it's more used in open letters (to journals for example). There are other formulas, for example:

- In a job application:

  > Al jefe/a (encargado/a) del departamento de Recursos Humanos

  or even:

  > A la atención del departamento de Recursos Humanos
- In a letter to wholesalers/ stores/... :

  > A la atención del departamento comercial.
- More general:

  > Apreciado/a Señor/a (lit. Dear Sir or Madam)

Answer (score 5):

One more acceptable form is:

> A quien pueda interesar

I've seen this form used on documents issued by government agencies (ie. certificates of some kind)

BTW, [Google](http://translate.google.com/?sl=auto&tl=es&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&text=&file=#auto%7Ces%7CTo%20whom%20it%20may%20concern%0A) translates it as `A quien pueda interesar`

Comment: In most cases "a quien pueda interesar" is just a poor literal translation from an English text. Not really used in Spanish (at least in Spain and Argentina)

Comment: In Venezuela this is the most common form used. In both personal and official communication.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a native speaker, but the phrase I was taught to use in "to whom it may concern" situations was:

> **Estimados señores**.

Comment: "Estimados señores" could be the equivalent, I think, to "Dear sir or madam". The OP asked for a different translation. Do you have any resources to support your answer?